# Default Legend does not fit in R Plot margins

Tags: r, plot, graph, visualization

I have searched so many techniques to solve it, but could not find the solution. Dataframe is the below:

```
 name                     n                                                                              geometry langs
   <chr>                <int>                                                                        <GEOMETRY [°]> <chr>
 1 Algeria                  1 POLYGON ((11.56067 24.09791, 10.77136 24.56253, 10.30385 24.37931, 9.948261 24.93695… Algerian Arabic/Darja
 2 Angola                   1 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.3756 -5.864241, 13.02487 -5.984389, 12.73517 -5.965682, 12.32243 … NA   
 3 Benin                    1 POLYGON ((2.749063 7.870734, 2.723793 8.506845, 2.912308 9.137608, 3.220352 9.444153… NA   
 4 Botswana                 1 POLYGON ((25.26423 -17.73654, 25.08444 -17.66182, 24.52071 -17.88712, 24.21736 -17.8… NA   
 5 Burkina Faso             1 POLYGON ((-2.963896 10.39533, -2.940409 10.96269, -1.203358 11.00982, -0.7615759 10.… NA   
 6 Burundi                  1 POLYGON ((29.75351 -4.452389, 30.11633 -4.090138, 30.50556 -3.568567, 30.75226 -3.35… NA   
 7 Cameroon                 1 POLYGON ((14.33781 2.227875, 15.14634 1.964015, 15.94092 1.727673, 16.01285 2.26764,… Hausa-Nigerian Pidgin
 8 Central African Rep.     1 POLYGON ((14.77655 6.408498, 14.53656 6.226959, 14.45941 5.451761, 14.55894 5.030598… NA   
 9 Chad                     1 POLYGON ((14.89336 12.21905, 14.96015 11.55557, 14.92356 10.89133, 15.46787 9.982337… NA   
10 Congo                    1 POLYGON ((13.25824 -4.882957, 13.60023 -4.500138, 14.14496 -4.510009, 14.20903 -4.79… NA   
11 Côte d'Ivoire            1 POLYGON ((-2.810701 5.389051, -3.24437 6.250472, -2.983585 7.379705, -2.56219 8.2196… NA   
12 Dem. Rep. Congo          1 POLYGON ((29.9535 4.173699, 29.716 4.600805, 29.15908 4.389267, 28.69668 4.455077, 2… NA   
13 Djibouti                 1 POLYGON ((42.77964 12.45542, 42.35156 12.54223, 42 12.1, 41.66176 11.6312, 41.73959 … NA   
14 Egypt                    1 POLYGON ((34.26544 31.21936, 33.7734 30.96746, 32.99392 31.02407, 32.19247 31.26034,… NA   
15 Eq. Guinea               1 POLYGON ((9.830284 1.067894, 11.28508 1.057662, 11.27645 2.261051, 9.649158 2.283866… NA   
16 Eritrea                  1 POLYGON ((42.77964 12.45542, 43.08123 12.69964, 42.58958 13.00042, 42.27683 13.34399… NA   
17 Ethiopia                 1 POLYGON ((37.59377 14.2131, 36.42951 14.42211, 36.27022 13.56333, 35.86363 12.57828,… Amharic-Oromo-Tigrinya
18 Gabon                    1 POLYGON ((11.85512 -3.426871, 11.47804 -2.765619, 11.82096 -2.514161, 12.4957 -2.391… NA   
19 Gambia                   1 POLYGON ((-15.9313 13.13028, -15.691 13.27035, -15.51181 13.27857, -15.14116 13.5095… NA   
20 Ghana                    1 POLYGON ((0.8369312 6.279979, 0.5703841 6.914359, 0.4909575 7.411744, 0.7120292 8.31… Hausa-Nigerian Pidgin-Twi
```

I want to plot the map of African languages wtih base `plot()` function and here is the code and the result:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2), mar = c(2,2,4,1),font = 7,font.axis = 7, 
    fg = "azure4",  col.axis = "azure4", cex.axis = .75)
plot(african_langs[3:4])
```

[image]

As you see from the graph, default legend does not fit the plot window. I have also tried to change the window size with the code below:

```
dev.new(width = 550, height = 330, unit = "px")
```

How to solve this problem?

Note: Adding a legend function is also not solving the problem as i want to see. I want to display the default legend correctly.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the data you plot so that others can reproduce it?
Remember that `par(mar)` is in lines, not inches (unlike `par(mai)`). Perhaps setting
`par(mar = c(2, 2, 4, 6), xpd = TRUE)` will show some difference (the rightmost number is the right margin).

Comment: @AliOsman best way to show the data is `dput(df)` where `df` is your dataframe

Comment: Sure, I get the data with `dput(df)` function.